# Node.js Server-Sent-Events - when to use response.flushHeaders() vs. response.writeHead()

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I am writing the server-side portion of an application in NodeJS with Express, which will use Server-Sent-Events (SSE).
I have a solution that seems to work, but need to understand whether there is a better way of doing it in Node.

The relevant portion of code currently looks like this:

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
};
res.writeHead(200, headers);

// Do more stuff [...]
```

where `res` is the response object.

Instead of calling `res.writeHead()`, I have seen other examples use `res.flushHeaders()`:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
res.flushHeaders();
```

Is there a difference between the two and is one preferable to the other, with respect to SSE and keeping a connection open to send messages?

Comment: Do you get chunks of data at client side when you do res.writeHead ? Or do you get chunks of data at client side with res.flushHeaders ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. In addition to Walters response I found the following:

`writeHead` and `flushHeaders` are both methods `expressjs` uses from `nodejs` and you don't need to use one of those two to properly implement [`SSE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events). For passing headers you'll need `writeHead` or `setHeader`.

`response.flushHeaders()` is [used when you need to bypass buffering the request headers](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_flushheaders). From testing, I can confirm it's not needed for `SSE` to work properly. So using it will be based on your specific application communication needs, not the needs of `SSE`.

Using `response.writeHead()` is a preferred alternative to using `setHeader`. [If progressive population of headers is desired with potential future retrieval and modification, use `response.setHeader()` instead](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers).

Neither `writeHead` or `flushHeaders` are used to keep the connection open. The connection will stay open by default until the client disconnects or you close it on the server with `response.end()` or `response.send()` [which will call `end`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/06d11755c99fe4c1cddf8b889a687448b568472d/lib/response.js#L107). The exception to that is [the HTTP default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761025/why-is-eventsource-connection-closed-every-30-60-sec-when-no-data-transported-w).

Explicitly specifying a `statusCode` code is based on your usage but not needed (*unless you use [`response.writeHead()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers)*). For example you [can use a response code to tell a client to stop reconnecting by using a HTTP 204 No Content response code](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#server-sent-events).

**Note**: For `expressjs` users using `compression`, make sure you call the `res.flush()` method ([provided by the `compression` middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/blob/3fea81d0eaed1eb872bf3e0405f20d9e175ab2cf/index.js#L70)) after your `res.write()` per [the docs](https://github.com/expressjs/compression).

Here is a [repo with complete example](https://github.com/jtlindsey/nuxt_server_sent_events_example). For the server `sse` portion see [this file](https://github.com/jtlindsey/nuxt_server_sent_events_example/blob/main/express-server/sse.js).

Answer (score 1):

They are practically equivalent because `res.write()` flushes the headers along with its first chunk. For SSE you're very likely needing an immediate response, at the very least to indicate successful connection. `res.setHeader()` can be useful if you later need to access or modify header state, but that doesn't seem relevant to SSE.

See nodejs.org documentation for [response.write()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) and [response.setHeader()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value).