# PHP SSE (EventSource) timeout every 2 minutes

Tags: php, asynchronous, process, pthreads

1. I'm using this [Mozilla SSE example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)
2. I added inside the loop a sample [PHP proc_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) example.
3. Run from browser, everything works fine.

The only problem is `proc_open()` execute a command that can take more than 2 minute to finish, which make the browser timeout after 2 minutes only. And our server use non-thread PHP.

**Question:**

How I can make the PHP script send something to the browser while waiting for `proc_open()` to finish in a non-thread PHP script ?.

**Code:**

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

$counter = rand(1, 10);
while (true) {
    // Run a local command
    $descriptorspec = array(
       0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
       1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
       2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
    );
    
    $cwd = '/tmp';
    $env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');
    
    $process = proc_open('HelloWorldProgram', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
    
    if (is_resource($process)) {
        // $pipes now looks like this:
        // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
        // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
        // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt
    
        fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
        fclose($pipes[0]);
    
        echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
    
        // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
        // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
        $return_value = proc_close($process);
    
        echo "command returned $return_value\n";
    }


    // Every second, send a "ping" event.
    
    echo "event: ping\n";
    $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
    echo 'data: {"time": "' . $curDate . '"}';
    echo "\n\n";
    
    // Send a simple message at random intervals.
    
    $counter--;
    
    if (!$counter) {
    echo 'data: This is a message at time ' . $curDate . "\n\n";
    $counter = rand(1, 10);
    }
    
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    
    // Break the loop if the client aborted the connection (closed the page)
    
    if ( connection_aborted() ) break;
    
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this in one of my project so use this line `set_time_limit(0);` in the start of your script like this

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
set_time_limit(0);//this will prevent the script to stop
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I added, indeed the script still alive, but I guess the browser timeout in 2 minutes if no data coming.

Comment: In fact I found an explanation and how to keep the connection alive but I don't know id that works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761025/why-is-eventsource-connection-closed-every-30-60-sec-when-no-data-transported-w

Comment: The other topic propose to use WebSocket instead of SSE, In my case I can't do the switch, but I just solved the issue with a work around (I will share it).

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

If someone had the same issue, I did this workaround which send a "Ping" to the browser while your real command is running and waiting to finish.

MyScript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

for task in "$@"; do {
  $task &
} done

while true; do {
  echo "Ping";
  sleep 30;
} done
```

**Use:**

```
$ sh MyScript.sh "Your Command Here With All Arguments"
Ping
Ping
Ping
```

If you setup correctly the SSE, you browser will receive "*Ping*" every 30 seconds in the same time your command is running so your browser will never timeout.